# PHP Sessions getting mixed up across two seperate applications

Tags: php, session

I am utilizing PHP (7.3) sessions for user authentication.

Application # 1 has been in place for many years and working well.

I recently created Application # 2 on the same server on a different path.

If I log into application # 1, then navigate to App # 2, it is picking up the session for App # 1 and allowing access without logging in.

Can anyone offer any advise how to create distinct PHP sessions that are unique to each application?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Daniel

Comment: Sessions are per-domain, although you can make them per-directory by using `session_set_cookie_data()`. So all applications in the same domain usually share session data.

Comment: You can also set an entirely different cookie name using [session_name()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.session-name.php)

Comment: I think more clarity is needed regarding how your application is handling sessions, and how the URLs are structured.  Why don't you post some code?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path

Comment: Some quality content here, I will be trying your suggestions shortly. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache, you can add this line to your projects in your `.htaccess` file. Don't forget to change the domain name.

```
php_value session.cookie_domain exemple.com
```

This should split the session in your applications

Comment: Or place it in your vhost declaration blocks if you have them and don't use .htaccess files at all.

Comment: Why not use a  .htaccess file? What could be the threat?

Comment: Think there are some performance implications. https://strategiq.co/does-the-number-of-htaccess-rules-impact-performance-and-scalability/ "Given that we now know that .htaccess files are being processed on every request and that there is a delay whilst they are processed..." Another one to look at is `fallback resource` when it comes to rewrite rules. Let's say 2.4 best practices.

Comment: "You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server."- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: I do have access to the config files, this sounds like the way to go. Will be trying this out first. Thanks for the assistance. Much appreciated.